# While using JDBDTemplate object with update method i'm getting below error.What i do?

Tags: spring, dao

The type org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

Comment: Please add more and relevant details of your question.

Comment: jt.update(WITHDRAW_QUERY, amount, account);                                                                                                             
 - The type org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
  from required .class files
 - The type org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
  referenced from required .class files